# Haskell List function (map, zip, etc..) with fix

Tags: list, haskell, fixpoint-combinators

I try to learn haskell and have exercise -try to rewrite standart list operation(map, foldr, zip, iterate, etc.) with function fix.
I have example with repeat:

```
repeat a = fix $ \xs -> a : xs
```

and it's further simplify

```
repeat a = fix (a:)
repeat = fix . (:)
```

Can anyone help me with map? 
Sorry for my bad engl and thank u in advance.

Comment: This is far too broad. Show what you've tried what note what specifically you need help with.

Comment: It's probably worth looking at - or trying to come up with (it's not hard) - the recursive definition of `map` first. Then I believe there's a fairly "mechanical" way to translate that into using `fix`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To use `fix`, one needs to write the recursive definition in the form

```
map = .... something involving map ....
```

Then, we let

```
map = fix (\m -> .... something involving m ....)
```

For instance,

```
map = \f xs -> case xs of
   []   -> []
   y:ys -> f y : map f ys
```

so,

```
map = fix (\m f xs -> case xs of
   []   -> []
   y:ys -> f y : m f ys)
```

Alternatively, since the argument `f` is the same for each recursive call, we can let

```
map f = \xs -> case xs of
   []   -> []
   y:ys -> f y : map f ys
```

and obtain

```
map f = fix (\m xs -> case xs of
   []   -> []
   y:ys -> f y : m ys)
```

Comment: Thanks! It's really useful. With it i could write filter and foldr, it's not so complicated.